# Tap and hold to add pin google maps api ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, dictionary

I want to tap and hold in `map` to add pin with `google maps api`.
Is it some tutorial for `IOS`?

`GMSMarker *marker`;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620322/gmsmarker-not-showing-in-1-3

Comment: its not what Im trying to do

Answer (score 4):

Can you add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your GMSMapView like you can with an MKMapView? I'm not on a Mac right now, so I can't test this theory.

If so, detect the on-screen touch location with locationInView:

```
- (void)handleLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    CGPoint pointInView = [gesture locationInView:mapView];
}
```

Then find the location coordinates relative to the point on the screen:

`CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
    [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: point];`

Then following the Google Maps SDK documentation [Add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#add_a_marker)

```
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinate];
marker.title = @"Hello World";
marker.map = mapView;
```

Hope that helps, or sets you on the right track. Sorry I can't test it works right now!

Comment: It`s work! Thank you. I use it
'UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self
                                          action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.3; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];'